# CLoin for Mac OS X: non-apple java is not supported

Tags: java, macos, clion

I installed the `CLoin 1.05` on my Mac, and it says

> Unsupported JVM: non-apple java is not supported

It guides me to download the Apple's java from [Java for OS X](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

What is the different between Oracle's java and Apple's java? Must I download the Apple's java ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message

> Unsupported JVM: non-apple java is not supported

Means that yes, if you want to use `CLoin 1.05` on your Mac you'll need to install the Apple JVM.

### JetBrains Support (Mac OS X)

#### [Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827547-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under)

says (in part)

> At the moment all our products require Apple JDK 1.6 to be installed in order to run on Mac. JDK 1.7 from Oracle is not officially supported yet and has known problems that stop us from using it by default. Oracle JDK 1.7.0_40 has added support for Retina and works much better than previous versions on Mac. You are welcome to give it a try in case you have any problems with Apple JDK.
>
> To force running under JDK 1.7 edit `/Applications/<Product>.app/Contents/Info.plist` file, change JVMVersion from 1.6* to 1.7* :
>
> ```
> <key>JVMVersion</key>
> <string>1.7*</string>
> ```

Comment: What is the different between Oracle's java and Apple's java? What is the reason in the hood ?

Comment: @ChenZhongPu Edited to add quotes from the official support site.